# Why there is nothing in my recyclerview on the screen even though datas are shared on API?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, retrofit, rx-java

I am trying to get data from local by using GET method. Here is Service codes.

This is Interface of API

```
interface API {
    @GET("WeatherForeCast")
    fun getweather(): Single<List<Data>>
}
```

and here is APIService class of API:

```
class APIService {
    private val BASE_URL="http://localhost:5000/"
    private val api=Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(API::class.java)

    fun getData(): Single<List<Data>> {
        return api.getweather()
    }

}
```

and here VİEWMODEL:

```
class APIViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val data = MutableLiveData<List<Data>>()
    val error = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val loading= MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    private val apiService=APIService()
    private val disposable=CompositeDisposable()

    fun refreshdata(){
        getfrominternet()
    }

    private fun getfrominternet(){
        loading.value=true
        disposable.add(
            apiService.getData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(object :DisposableSingleObserver<List<Data>>(){
                    override fun onSuccess(t: List<Data>) {
                        data.value=t
                        error.value=false
                        loading.value=false

                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        error.value=true
                        loading.value=true
                    }

                })

        )
    }


}
```

and here is ActivityMain.kt file that I made everthing on.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerview: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var list: List<Data>
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerviewAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        list= listOf()
        adapter=RecyclerviewAdapter(list)
        binding.recyclerview.adapter= adapter
        binding.recyclerview.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)

    }

}
```

I was expecting to see datas that I have shared on the screen of the emulator. But there is nothing that I have been seen. There is no any bug too. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Your code in the Activity makes no attempt to connect the ViewMode's `data` property to the RecyclerView's adapter.

Answer (score 1):

create a liveData in your viewModel and observer that data in your activity, when you get response from server, notify the data.
when you get the data, your observer in activity will be called, that is where you should put your add data to your adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method

example:

in your viewModel:

```
private val _data = MutableLiveData<List<Data>>()
    val data: LiveData<List<Data>> get() = _summaryBehavior

private fun getfrominternet(){
        loading.value=true
        disposable.add(
            apiService.getData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(object :DisposableSingleObserver<List<Data>>(){
                    override fun onSuccess(t: List<Data>) {
                        _data.value=t
                        error.value=false
                        loading.value=false


                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        error.value=true
                        loading.value=true
                    }

                })

        )
    }
```

in your activity or fragment:

```
with(viewModel){
            data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                adapter.setData(it)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list= listOf()
adapter=RecyclerviewAdapter(list)
```

You are passing the adapter an empty list here. I would recommend having the viewModel passed to the adapter and then observe the mutableLiveData such that when it updates you add the items to the adapter and notify it of the change.